# Sum values from different select unions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

i have the next problem:

if you see the image, i want Add or Subtract VALUES, but to be honest, i don't know how start?

[image]

this is how i get this result

```
select position, position_1, TIPO_RESUMEN, CONCEPT, to_char(NVL(VALUE,0) ,'FM999G999G999G999G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') as VALUE
from (
    SELECT 1 position, 10 position_1, 'Expense' TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Expected expense' CONCEPT ,sum(IMP_GA_GU) VALUE from table_1 tg where UPPER(tg.cod) = 'USER_1' and tg.cod_fol = :P10_FOL and tg.prod_cuad = :P10_PROD and tg.fecha_inicio = :P10_FEC_INI and tip_ga = 'PREVISTO'
    union
    SELECT 2 position, 20 position_2, 'Expense' TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Unforeseen expense' CONCEPT ,sum(IMP_GA_GU) VALUE from table_2 tp where UPPER(tp.cod) = 'USER_1' and tp.cod_fol = :P10_FOL and tp.prod_cuad = :P10_PROD and tp.fecha_inicio = :P10_FEC_INI and tp.tip_ga = 'NO_PREVISTO'
    union
    SELECT 3 position, 30 position_3, 'Expense' TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Total' CONCEPT , 0 VALUE from dual
);
```

And i need to Total Value be a SUM of (Expected expense + Unforeseen expense)

Can anybody help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As it is about Oracle Application Express, I'd suggest you to let Apex do that job; it is more than capable of doing it. How? Just create a report (classic or interactive, doesn't matter).

What is important is that you should - somehow - know which values are positive and which are negative.

If you store them as such into a table, even better. If not, use `CASE` so that values on the screen really are displayed as such (positive/negative). Then:

- for interactive report, go to "Actions" menu, pick "Data" and "Aggregate"; use "Sum" function on the `value` column
- for classic report, go to `value` column's properties and check the "Compute sum" property

Quite simple, is it not?

If you opt to do everything manually, well, it'll be a lot of coding/effort for a questionable result. You know what Apex says on the homepage?

> Build enterprise apps 20x faster with 100x less code

I suggest you do that.

Comment: this part is a project done by someone and this part was done in this way, i can modify because could spend more time (something that i don't have). So there is an option to do it by query?. Regards

Comment: I suppose. Use CASE (or DECODE) to distinguish positive from negative values and apply SUM to such values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE and then `union all`:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as position, 10 as position_1, 'Expense' as TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Expected expense' as CONCEPT , sum(IMP_GA_GU) as VALUE
      from table_1 tg
      where UPPER(tg.cod) = 'USER_1' and tg.cod_fol = :P10_FOL and tg.prod_cuad = :P10_PROD and tg.fecha_inicio = :P10_FEC_INI and tip_ga = 'PREVISTO'
      union all
      select 2 as position, 20 as position_2, 'Expense' as TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Unforeseen expense' as CONCEPT, sum(IMP_GA_GU) as VALUE
      from table_2 tp 
      where UPPER(tp.cod) = 'USER_1' and tp.cod_fol = :P10_FOL and tp.prod_cuad = :P10_PROD and tp.fecha_inicio = :P10_FEC_INI and tp.tip_ga = 'NO_PREVISTO'
     )
select cte.*
from cte
union all
select 3 as position, 30 as position_3, 'Expense' as TIPO_RESUMEN, 'Total' as CONCEPT , sum(value)
from cte
```